# How to unit test WebWorker code with jest?

Tags: jestjs, web-worker

I have this simple webworker which does some polling:

```
import { fetchLatestResults } from '../backend/fetchLatestResults';

let polling = false;
let symbolIds: string[] = [];

const fetchLatest = async () => {

  if (!symbolIds.length) {
    return;
  }

  try {
    const results = await fetchLatestResults(symbolIds);
    self.postMessage(results);
  } catch (e) {
    // noop for now
  }
};

if (!polling) {
  polling = true;
  fetchLatest();
  setInterval(fetchLatest, 10 * 1000);
}

self.onmessage = (e: MessageEvent) => {
  symbolIds = e.data;
  fetchLatest();
};
```

How can I unit test this with jest? There is not a lot of code, business logic is extracted, but still there are few cases that I'd like to test, like that `fetchLatestResults` is not invoked until `symbolIds` are set, etc. ?

I could probably extract `onmessage` logic into a function, export it, import it on tests, and call it, but what about `postMessage` ?

Comment: Unit test is for testing whether parts (units) of code do what they are meant to. You should be able to test the parts of the code that makes the worker work independently of whether they run in a worker or not.